# custom layout in nativescript camera plus on android not at all visible

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I am using [nativescript-camera-plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) for custom Layout. I tried default icons first which was working fine, but when i put custom gridlayout inside cam then it was not visible.

I have made all icon visible to false when i was checking, but now i just put a general code to show where i'm facing problem.

```
<Cam:CameraPlus id="camPlus" loaded="camLoaded" height="{{ cameraHeight }}" galleryPickerMode="multiple" enableVideo="true" confirmVideo="false" saveToGallery="true" showCaptureIcon="false" showGalleryIcon="false" showToggleIcon="false" showFlashIcon="false" confirmPhotos="true" flashOffIcon="icon" autoSquareCrop="true" insetButtons="true" insetButtonsPercent="0.02" imagesSelectedEvent="{{ imagesSelectedBinding }}" debug="true">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto" columns="auto, *, auto"><Button row="0" col="0" text="Flash" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ toggleFlash }}" /><Button row="0" col="2" text="Camera" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ toggleCamera }}" /><Image row="1" col="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" src="https://img.clipartfest.com/4ec5e2315cea92482da5546e1e7fca89_-pinterest-cute-clipart-snowman-clipart-transparent-background_300-300.png" stretch="none" /><Button row="2" col="0" text="Gallery" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ openGallery }}" /><Button row="2" col="2" text="Take" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ takePic }}" /></GridLayout>
  </Cam:CameraPlus>
```

Comment: Do you have a Github sample where we can see the issue?

Comment: @Manoj  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zNigfq

Comment: Your playground sample is terminating immediately. JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: `SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: @NarendraMongiya sorry for inconvenience, may be that error is because of using ios i think.  i tested this in android redmi 3s mobile. and it was working fine. can you have a look at the below link which i just tested and saved now.  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zNigfq&v=2

Comment: Still terminating. file:///app/@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus/camera-plus.js:155:68: JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate

Comment: That playground is working in android, what is the problem that your are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bug with the plugin itself. Here is a workaround,

**XML**

```
<Cam:CameraPlus id="camPlus" loaded="camLoaded" height="{{ cameraHeight }}">
                <GridLayout id="overlay" rows="auto, *, auto" columns="auto, *, auto">
                    <Button row="0" col="0" text="Flash" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ toggleFlash }}" />
                    <Button row="0" col="2" text="Camera" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ toggleCamera }}" />
                    <Image row="1" col="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" src="https://img.clipartfest.com/4ec5e2315cea92482da5546e1e7fca89_-pinterest-cute-clipart-snowman-clipart-transparent-background_300-300.png" stretch="none" />
                    <Button row="2" col="0" text="Gallery" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ openGallery }}" />
                    <Button row="2" col="2" text="Take" class="btn-transparent" tap="{{ takePic }}" />
                </GridLayout>
            </Cam:CameraPlus>
```

**JS**

```
function camLoaded(args) {
    const parentView = args.object.nativeView;
    const overlayView = args.object.page.getViewById("overlay");
    parentView.removeView(overlayView.nativeView);
    overlayView.nativeView.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    parentView.addView(overlayView.nativeView);
}
```

Comment: this is perfectly working......   https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=zNigfq&v=3

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work on Playground. Anyone wishes to test it would have to run the  code locally on your machine.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting, i tested this sample on my two android devices. its working fine. moreover the code was in playground, then why it will not work. anyhow thanks for the answer.

Comment: My bad, I kept iOS in mind which depends on a native library. Android should be fine.